# Find particular solution of $D^3y+Dy=\sin(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I start by trying to find a particular solution of $D^3y+Dy=e^{ix}$ and then I will take the imaginary part. Let $P(D)=D^3+D$. We are looking for a solution in the form of $u(x)e^{ix}$. Using the exponential shift theorem $$P(D)u(x)e^{-ix}=e^{ix}P(D+i)u(x)$$

Since this is equal to $e^{ix}$, we have $P(D+i)u(x)=1$. But $P(i)=0$. So the next step is to factor out some $D$ operators but for each factorization, $P(i)=0$. I am stuck.

Comment: Why don't you find $\frac{1}{P(D)} \sin x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment the particular solution is given by

> $$y = \frac{1}{P(D)} \sin(x). $$

See the [table](http://www.efunda.com/math/ode/linearode_invoperator.cfm).

Comment: According to the table the answer is the imaginary component of $\frac{e^{ix}}{P(i)}$ but $P(i)=i^3+i=-i+i=0$.

Comment: Yes but if you read carefully then you can see that $P'(i) \neq 0$ so according to the table $m=1$! Can you see it now?

Answer (score 1):

Let $u(x)$ be a polynomial whose degree is equal to or less than $3$. Then we can set
$$
u(x)=a_0+a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3.
$$
and so
\begin{align}
u'(x)&=a_1  + 2a_2 x + 3a_3 x^2\\
u''(x)&= 2a_2  + 6a_3 x\\
u'''(x)&=6a_3.
\end{align}
If you substitute $u(x)e^{ix}$ in given differential equation, since
\begin{align}
Dy&=(u'(x)+iu(x))e^{ix}\\
D^3y&=(u'''(x)+3iu''(x)-3u'(x)-iu(x))e^{ix},
\end{align}
we get
$$
u'''(x)+3iu''(x)-2u'(x)=1.
$$
Then
$$
6a_3+3i(2a_2+6a_3 x) - 2(a_1 + 2a_2 x +3a_3 x^2)=1.
$$
Comparing coefficients, we get following system of linear equations:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 6i & 6\\
0 & -4 & 18i\\
0 & 0 & -6
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$ are uniquely determined. ($a_0$ is a free variable)

Comment: Although this is a good answer, I'm looking for one that involves inverse operators.